# Calculate bigO notation of recursive relation

Tags: computer-science, computational-complexity

I am attempting to calculate the big O notation for a simple recurrence relation
$$T(n) =  T(n/2) + 1\quad\text{when}\enspace n ≥ 1$$

$$T(1) = 1$$

So my attempt was as follows

$$T(n) \le T(\frac{n}{2}) + 1 \\
T(\frac{n}{2}) \le T(\frac{n}{4}) + 1 \\
... \\
\\
T(n) + T(\frac{n}{2}) + T(\frac{n}{4}) + ... \le T(\frac{n}{2}) + T(\frac n4) + \dots + 1 + 1 + \dotsm\\$$

Since we can subtract $T(\frac n2), T(\frac n4)$ etc from both sides we can get

$$T(n) \le n \\
T(n) = T(\frac n2) + 1 \Rightarrow O(n)$$

But i was also given to understand that  for recurrence relations the following stands:

$$T(n)=O(n^{\log_BA}), A > B^k \\
T(n)=O(n^k\log n),A=B^k \\
T(n)=O(n^k),A<B^k$$
Such that the recurrence relation is of the form $T(n)=AT(\frac nB) + O(n^k)$

If this were true would we not have the second case since $A=1 \; B=2 \  k =0$. So $1=2^0$So according to this the big O should be $O(n^0\log n)=O(\log n)$

Which one is right and why.
Sorry for any formatting problems this is my first post.

Answer (score 0):

For positive integer $n
\geq 2$ we have $T(2^{n-1})=n $ by induction on $n$ . If $T(x)$ is defined for other values of $x$ and if $T$ is monotonic, then for $2^{n-1}<x<2^n$ we have $0<n=T(2^{n-1}\leq T(x)  \leq T(2^n)= (n+1)$, so for all $x\geq 2$ we have $0<T(x)\leq 2+\log_2 x \leq 3 \log_2 x.$